# Como usar o border-radius no CSS?

Tags: css

Bom tipo eu sei como usar o *border-radius* mais eu vi em um site que eles usavam o *border-radius: 50px / 50px* tipo ele arredonda os cantos da borda e com esse segundo valor ele arrendonda tipo mais ainda na vertical mais oque quer dizer esse */*

Answer (score 3):

Olá, tudo bem?

A propriedade **border-radius** do **CSS** pode receber até quatro valores.

Ex:

```
border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
```

O primeiro valor aplica-se ao canto superior esquerdo, o segundo valor aplica-se ao canto superior direito, o terceiro valor aplica-se ao canto inferior direito e o quarto valor aplica-se ao canto inferior esquerdo.

Como estamos falando da **"/"**, um valor representa o quanto vai definir horizontalmente e a outra verticalmente referente aquele canto.

```
border-radius: 40px / 20px;
   horizontal --^      ^-- vertical
```

Segue a imagem para você entender melhor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter lhe ajudado, caso ainda houver dúvidas, segue o link para lhe ajudar melhor:
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: Opa valeu broder ajudou  bastante valeu mesmo hehe